# Play/Pause button for my automatic jquery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

So I have an automatic jquery slider which I want to control via a play/pause button. Currently the slider starts on page load but I want to be able to start/pause it with a play button, class=heart.

I want the image with play class to be the play/pause button.

I currently have no idea how to do this, here is my code:

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides1");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    setTimeout(showSlides, 7000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

```css
.polaroid1{
 box-shadow: 10px 10px 7px -7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; 
 transform: rotate(-8deg); 
 margin-bottom:30px; 
 width:380px; 
 height:320px; 
 background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0); 
 text-align:right; 
 padding-top:10px; 
 padding-right:10px; 
 padding-left:10px; 
 padding-bottom:15px; 
 top:15px; 
 left:25px; 
 position:relative;
}

.photo1{
 width:100%;  
 height:85%; 
 position:relative;
 padding:5px;
}

.date1{
 margin:0; 
 padding-right:10px; 
 font-family: 'Covered By Your Grace', cursive; 
 transform: rotate(-5deg);
 font-size:28px;
}

.mySlides1{
 display:none;
 width:380px; 
 height:320px; 
 position:absolute; 
 top:0px; 
 left:0px;
}

.play{
 position:absolute; 
 left:5px; 
 bottom:5px; 
 cursor:pointer; 
 z-index:10000;
}
```

```html
<div class="polaroid1">
  <img class="play" src="images/heart.png">
  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/IMG-20170610-WA0028.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">22-05-2017</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/20170812_181516.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">12-08-2017</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/20170522_112958.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">22-05-2017</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I edited your example. Call startSlides() to start the slider, and stopSlides() to stop it. The main idea is to clear the timeout when stopping and set it again when starting.

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
var stop = false;
var sliderTimeout;
showSlides();

function click() {
   if (stop) {
       startSlides();
   } else {
       stopSlides();
   }
}

function stopSlides() {
    clearTimeout(sliderTimeout);
    stop = true;
}

function startSlides() {
    stop = false;
    showSlides();
} 

function showSlides() {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides1");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    if (!stop) {
        sliderTimeout = setTimeout(showSlides, 7000); // Change image every 2 seconds
    }
}
```

```css
.polaroid1{
 box-shadow: 10px 10px 7px -7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; 
 transform: rotate(-8deg); 
 margin-bottom:30px; 
 width:380px; 
 height:320px; 
 background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0); 
 text-align:right; 
 padding-top:10px; 
 padding-right:10px; 
 padding-left:10px; 
 padding-bottom:15px; 
 top:15px; 
 left:25px; 
 position:relative;
}

.photo1{
 width:100%;  
 height:85%; 
 position:relative;
 padding:5px;
}

.date1{
 margin:0; 
 padding-right:10px; 
 font-family: 'Covered By Your Grace', cursive; 
 transform: rotate(-5deg);
 font-size:28px;
}

.mySlides1{
 display:none;
 width:380px; 
 height:320px; 
 position:absolute; 
 top:0px; 
 left:0px;
}

.play{
 position:absolute; 
 left:5px; 
 bottom:5px; 
 cursor:pointer; 
 z-index:10000;
}
```

```html
<div class="polaroid1">
  <img class="play" src="images/heart.png">
  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/IMG-20170610-WA0028.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">22-05-2017</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/20170812_181516.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">12-08-2017</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/20170522_112958.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">22-05-2017</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How can I toggle between start and stop function if I am controling it from ONE single button, which is this image: <img class="play" src="images/heart.png">  bear in mind I am a newbie and my js skills are lacking

Comment: I just edited my post. You must call the click function everytime you click on the image.

Comment: I will try this later, have to go now Thank you